# What is a "double touchie"?

Tags: videoball

Sometimes the game announces a "double touch-y" and it's not entirely clear what this means. Is it a second touchdown? A score made by shooting a Level 2 shot? A score made by two different players hitting the ball?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It is a Level 2 shot. I remember playing this game and I found out it is a Level 2 shot.